# How to save bearer token received from OpenID

Tags: open-id-connect

**Use case**
We are trying to implement a openID based authentication flow with Salesforce as the service provider.

Post the successful authentication of a user we need to pass the bearer token received from identity provider (as part of SSO) to mule in the body for API calls

**Problem**
I am not able to find out a configuration in Salesforce where I can save the bearer token.

**Things explored**

1. Name credential : I am not able to find a way to use 2 name credentials in a callout (one received from OpenID and another one for mule)

Comment: You won't be able to do this out of the box. You'll need to roll your own auth provider.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
Configure an Open ID Authentication Provider ([link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5)).

**Step 2**
Define a Named Credential with the configured Authentication Provider in Step 1 ([link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_define.htm&type=5)).

Note the additional step each user must perform in order to obtain an access token from their personal settings if your named credential's Identity Type is set to *Per User*.